# Why is my bullet moving through my enemy and not detecting a collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have my Unity 2D project set up so that the bullet is a trigger and will detect and collisions but not interact with the environment, and my enemy being a collider so that it will do both. I don't know if the fact that they are two different types affects collisions, but I thought I'd include that detail incase it did. I know this issue is not caused by my bullet moving too quickly since when I turn the speed of the bullet down the issue persists. I will include the code for the enemy collision and the bullet collision detection here:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Proj") {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Hit");
    }
```

Now for the bullet:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
{
    if (hitInfo.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
    Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

The bullet is detecting a collision with an enemy and deleting itself, but the enemy is not detecting a collision with the bullet and taking damage/deleting itself. Even when I turn off the Destroy(gameObject) part of the bullet code so that it doesn't destroy itself on collision I still have the same problem so I know it isn't matter of it deleting before anything detects. I hope I was thorough enough with my explanation and that someone can help me resolve this issue.
Image of the inspectors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4O0l.jpg

Comment: we need to see the inspector to be able to actually the settings of each collider and tags etc...

Comment: if the speed is too high the collision could be ignored. i can answer a solution if it is th case.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TLfcNcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bullet needs to be a non-trigger collider as you are calling OnCollisionEnter and not OnTriggerEnter from the enemy script.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the settings of each collider, also [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) and [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) are 2 different things, and will occur in different conditions, so make sure that you are using the right one for the player.

Comment: Each use a box collider with default settings, the only thing changed is on the bullet I have IsTrigger set to true.

Comment: The trigger disables collision enter stuff, hopefully [this] (https://answers.unity.com/questions/454479/toggling-is-trigger-on-box-collider-causes-it-to-n.html#:~:text=2%20Replies&text=Hello.,it%20into%20a%20passable%20trigger.&text=So%20in%20other%20words%2C%20the,the%20trigger%20for%20your%20GameObject.) unity forum post can answer your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with trigger behaviour, as it's been a while since I've played around with those, but [this bit of documentation for MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) is an important starting point for solving your problem:

> Trigger events are only sent if one of the Colliders also has a Rigidbody2D attached.

I can't say for sure, but your screenshots suggest that there is no `Rigidbody2D` involved.

---

### Interestingly,

documentation for [Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) neglects to specify that a `Rigidbody2D` is necessary. I'm not sure what this implies; both [MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter(Collider)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) and [Collider.OnTriggerEnter(Collider)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) (the 3D analogues) are said to require a `RigidBody`. Both of these pages also claim

> If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens.

However, the example code from `Monobehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D)` claims that setting both 2D colliders as triggers will still allow the function to be called.